# Can't get user association working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been struggling to get an association working. A user `has_many :campaigns` and a campaign `belongs_to :user`

but when I try to create a new campaign, it gives me an error saying campaigns is an invalid method

```
def index
    @campaigns = Campaign.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /campaigns/1
  # GET /campaigns/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /campaigns/new
  def new
    @campaign = current_user.campaigns.build
  end

  # GET /campaigns/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /campaigns
  # POST /campaigns.json
    def create
    @campaign = current_user.campaigns.new(campaign_params)

    if @campaign.save
      redirect_to @campaign
    else
      render 'new'
    end
```

I already did all the user_id migration and stuff

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end



   class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :campaigns
end
```

Error Message: undefined method `campaigns' for #

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual error message and the model code please?

Comment: undefined method `campaigns' for #<User:0x007fc87a521698> is the error

Comment: updated model and error mssage

Comment: On which line did the error triggered?

Comment: @campaign = current_user.campaigns.build

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? It could be cached? Also, have you tried `current_user.campaigns.new` instead of `.build`?

Comment: Woo hoo, .new did the trick! Thanks!!

Comment: @Wilson What did the trick? Restarting? Might be good to post a proper answer to close the question...